# Visual Studio 2010 - how to replace many .resx lines by paste the new ones?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I have more than 1000 lines in each file (for different languages), all of them correspond to the existing names inside .resx file.

I'm trying just to paste the new values (I don't want to change the Names) to replace the existing ones, but VS 2010 treats them as a new content and puts them to the bottom of the file. Is there any tool or way to do it fast ?

Pasting each line by myself will cos me much time and effort. Any ideas ?

Comment: the question is confusing. Can you be more specific? 1000 lines in .cs file that are duplicated in the .resx? And now you want to essentially replace the text in code with the resx function name? Is that the question?

Comment: no, I have 1000 lines of raw text, in my .resx files I have the old text, and each line has unique Name. Now, I just want to replace the old text (the Values) to the new ones, and don't change the Name column values